# how to render form fields (not predefined) on the fly (according to user inputs) in angular4

Tags: angular

How do I render form fields according to user input in a text area in angular4. If user enters 3 variables in textarea, i have to provide 3 text fields with label, images and text field on the fly below the text area. User can enter any no of variables like 4, 5, 6 etc. Also, needs to provide java script action for that image (may be a popup window). I have tried dynamic forms as well as dynamic components, but both of them are not fitting into this requirement. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Adding more info -
If the user enters a + b = c in text area and click a button, I have to add text fields and images like below. I can do that in old way like below. But how can I achieve the same in Angular 4?

```
document.getElementById(‘divID’).innerHTML = “<table><tr><td> a : <input type=‘text’ name=‘a’ value=‘’”> <a href=‘#’ onclick=“openChild(a)”>some image</a></td> b : <input type=‘text’ name=‘b’ value=‘’”> <a href=‘#’ onclick=“openChild(b)”>some image</a></td></tr></table>;
```

Comment: Can you show your code or any error message?

Comment: you should provide code you have been trying with

Comment: Instead of telling us what you want, you should provide code on what you have tried and where you are having an issue. This is not a free coding service ;)

Comment: and please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Dynamic components with DomSanitizer to resolve the issue. In case if someone has the same problem.

Comment: your answer has the same problem as your question : you don't provide enough details to be useful for someone else.
How did you use Dynamic components with DomSanitizer ? Can you show some code ?

Comment: the innerHtml string you want to display can be sanitized as like this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(strHTML); where _sanitizer is the DomSanitizer. I had to change the code to accommodate some other things. Let me know if you need any other info.